# Parse Json response

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Can anyone please tell why my function B() is not giving giving response?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionID=null ;
    function A() {
        $.getJSON('http://url.php?id=login&email='+document.getElementById("txtemail").value+'&password='+document.getElementById("txtpassword").value,
                function (data) {sessionID = data.session_id;
                    alert(data.status);
                    alert(data.msg);
                    alert(data.user_id);
                    alert(sessionID);
                });
    }
    function B() {
        $.getJSON('http://url.php?id=chat_init&sess_d='+sessionID+'&user_id='+document.getElementById("user_id").value+    '&to_id='+document.getElementById("to_id").value,
                function (data) {
                    alert(data.status);
                    alert(data.msg);alert(data.room_id);
                });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Username :  <input type="text" id="txtemail" />
<br/><br/>
Password :  <input type="password" id="txtpassword"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="A()" /><br />
My id is :  <input type="text" id="user_id" /> <br /><br />
To ID is :  <input type="text" id="to_id"   /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="25">
</textarea><br /><br />
<textarea rows="2" cols="18"> </textarea>
<input type="button" value="Initialize chat"  onClick="B()">

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code

Comment: please use proper tags to display your code

Comment: please... do something about your markup first

Comment: i am not able to do so. otherwise  It says code is not properly indented.

Comment: If you copy the URL that is being generated in the `B` function and paste it into your browser, does it give you the expected results?

Comment: Can you post a link to jsFiddle? Thats a good alternative for code this size

Comment: @ Rick : Only function A() gives response. Not B()

Comment: Assuming that your URL is actually a valid one and `url.php` is just a place holder, I would generate the URL before the `getJSON` call and set a variable. Alert that URL variable to confirm it is what you expect.

Comment: @Craig : could you write the code plz?

Comment: I'm just suggesting that on the first line within your `B` function to write `var url = 'http://url.php?id=chat_init&sess_d='+sessionID+'&user_id='+document.getElementById("user_id").value+    '&to_id='+document.getElementById("to_id").value`...then `alert(url)` to verify this is EXACTLY what you expect...then use that `url` variable when you call `getJSON()`. Your source generally looks ok as long as you are not trying to access data from another domain in function `B`. Also, `onClick()` should be `onclick()` for your initialize chat button.

Comment: @ Craig : The values are coming perfect in alert. I did this : alert('http://url.php?id=chat_init&sess_d='+sessionID+'&user_id='+document.getElementById("user_id").value+'&to_id='+document.getElementById("to_id").value);

Comment: hmmm...are you sure the json is formatted correctly? If you paste the url from function `A` into a browser and do the same for function `B`...how does the format compare? That's about all I've got for you.

Answer (score 0):

When using this function, you should have a relative path instead of full.

Which means `http://url.php` should be `youscript.php`. I would also use the ajax-function instead of getJSON, but that is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Thats my clients' requirement.

Comment: Using full URL or getJSON? Is the script located in the same location as your js-file? You can't use these functions across domains. And `ajax`/`getJSON` is the same, I just like to be more in control, therefor favor the `ajax`-function.

Answer (score 0):

'http://url.php' is not a valid URL.

Use a relative ("url.php"), absolute ("/url.php"), or fully qualified ("http://www.example.com/url.php") URL.

**UPDATE**

`http://url.php` **will not** work on a public website.

The browser will attempt to resolve `url.php` to an IP address, which **will** fail.

Comment: Except the fully qualified one has to come from the same server unless you have CORS implemented

Comment: @SONALKASLIWAL con you confirm that `url.php` is just a place holder and does contain a valid URL? I'm assuming that since function `A` works that is the case.